# Error when running the new Stack Overflow Bot

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, botframework

I came across the new [Stack Overflow Bot by Microsoft](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Samples/tree/master/StackOverflow-Bot) on the Stack Overflow blog and decided to give it a try.

After installing Node V8.1.4 for macOS, I installed the bot by running `npm install` in the StackBot directory. There weren't many issues, except for a warning returned.

```
MacBook-Air:StackBot USER$ npm install
npm WARN stackbot@1.0.0 No repository field.

up to date in 1.248s
```

Afterwards, I tried running the bot, using `npm run start`. The bot failed to startup and gave this error.

```
MacBook-Air:StackBot USER$ npm run start

> stackbot@1.0.0 start /Users/USER/Downloads/BotFramework-Samples-master/StackOverflow-Bot/StackBot
> node index.js

Missing one of BOTBUILDER_APP_ID, BOTBUILDER_APP_PASSWORD,     LUIS_MODEL, KB_ID, QNA_KEY, QNA_URL, BING_SEARCH_CONFIG, BING_SEARCH_KEY,     TEXT_ANALYTICS_KEY, TEXT_ANALYTICS_URL, DIALOG_ANALYZER_CLIENTID, DIALOG_ANALYZER_KEY or DIALOG_ANALYZER_URL     in environment variables!
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! stackbot@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the stackbot@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/USER/.npm/_logs/2017-09-25T12_56_14_988Z-debug.log
```

The complete log is as follows:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@5.0.3
3 info using node@v8.1.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle stackbot@1.0.0~prestart: stackbot@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle stackbot@1.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle stackbot@1.0.0~start: stackbot@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle stackbot@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle stackbot@1.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/Users/USER/Downloads/BotFramework-Samples-master/StackOverflow-Bot/StackBot/node_modules/.bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
10 verbose lifecycle stackbot@1.0.0~start: CWD: /Users/USER/Downloads/BotFramework-Samples-master/StackOverflow-Bot/StackBot
11 silly lifecycle stackbot@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'node index.js' ]
12 silly lifecycle stackbot@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle stackbot@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: stackbot@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:283:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:213:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:897:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:208:5)
15 verbose pkgid stackbot@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd /Users/USER/Downloads/BotFramework-Samples-master/StackOverflow-Bot/StackBot
17 verbose Darwin 16.7.0
18 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "start"
19 verbose node v8.1.4
20 verbose npm  v5.0.3
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error errno 1
23 error stackbot@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
23 error Exit status 1
24 error Failed at the stackbot@1.0.0 start script.
24 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

What is causing this error and is there a way to solve this?

Comment: It says what the error is: you haven't set required environment variables (_"Missing one of..."_). Please refer to [this page](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Samples/tree/master/StackOverflow-Bot#configuration) on how to configure the bot.

Comment: Hey, how did you run npm install on stackBot directory? I mean what is that exactly?

Comment: ^^ I second Neel's comment.

Comment: Referring to that page did not help resolve the issue in my case @robertklep.  It has minimal instructions. There is no mention of environmental variable setting in the first two steps. The run start is step 2.

Comment: @QHarr the part of the page that is being linked to documents all environment variables, and also links to a page on how to actually set environment variables in general.

Comment: @robertklep Sorry if I sounded rude. Just frustrated. The environmentals shouldn't need adjusting if not using the VS SDK I thought. The install instructions seems to imply you only need the folder and Node JS 8.4+ and then simply execute two command line instructions from within the folder. This does not appear to be the case for me. The BOT is not up and running by this point.

Comment: @QHarr and you're getting a similar error (about missing environment variables)? In that case, you _do_ need to set them, I'd guess :D

Comment: @robertklep Thanks. It's Microsoft. Was an installer too much to ask for? Apparently with nodeJS involved...yes..

Answer (score 0):

have you try

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```